# alert message on button submit javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a little funky situation. I am using form spree on my static html site, where I want to alert a message saying `message sent successfully` after they click the submit button. Works fine, but it doesn't refresh the page as I hoped. this is what I have, I assumed this wouldn't work but I think this is a decent starting point:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("message successfully sent").then(response => {
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-defeault btn-send" value="Send message" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>
```

so as you can see, I am trying to say, hey, send the message, and then refresh the page. but it is not refreshing the page... any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't use `alert`, `prompt` or `confirm` in production. Old school form submission, which I don't recommend, should reload the page where the `<form action=`. I would use the `XMLHttpRequest` anyways. Don't reload the page.

Comment: the form itself doesn't actually refresh the page when I submit. I've never used `XMLHttpRequest`, could you show an example?

Comment: Don't use that either, the modern JS API for that is the Fetch API, which is just `fetch(url, {...options...}).then(...).catch(...)`. The legacy `XMLHttpRequest` is... drastically more code, and quite a bit less useful. Having said that: the reason _why_ you don't want alert, is because it's an ancient function. It does not return a promise, and cannot be `then`'d. It's a thread-blocking call, so any code that should happen after the user clicks "OK" would just be on the next line. Still: don't use alert/confirm/prompt, use a modern modal/dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("message successfully sent");
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-defeault btn-send" value="Send message" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: it doesn't send then form thought, it refreshed b4 it sends